# sort dict or list by second value of the tuple and then by the first one

Tags: python

I can't figure out why my code doesn't work, I have a list(or dict, i tried both) of tuples, I'd like to order it by the second value of the tuple and in case 2 tuples have the same second values, by the first one. I tried this:

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda k: (k[1], k[0]), reverse=True)
```

but what I get is a list sorted only by its second value...for example with this list:

```
l = [('ee',10), ('oo',11), ('aa', 10)]
```

I get this output:    `[('oo', 11), ('ee', 10), ('aa', 10)]`

but lexicographically, 'aa' comes before 'ee'...

what am I doing wrong? I tried with my_list.sort() or with a dict but nothing.

the problem is probably the "reverse true" condition, but what I'm trying to get is this output:     `[('oo', 11), ('aa', 10), ('ee', 10)]`

basically I want the reverse true applied only to the first condition of the lambda... it is possible?

Comment: You are sorting in reverse order, so the output is correct. Do you want to order the second column in the opposite order than the first one?

Comment: yeah... you got it, how could i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something as follows:

```
output = sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[1], [-ord(letter) for letter in x[0]]), reverse=True)
```

`output` will contain the following:

```
[('oo', 11), ('aa', 10), ('ee', 10)]
```

We are keeping the reverse order (descending), but we are passing a list as the second option (which are compared lexicographically by Python too) for sorting which will have the negative ASCII values for each letter. This way, `-ord('a')` (-97) is greater than `-ord('e')` (-101)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should remove the `reverse=True` option, so that values would be sorted in the "right" order.

```
>>> l = [('ee',10), ('oo',11), ('aa', 10)]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda k: (k[1], k[0]), reverse=False)
[('aa', 10), ('ee', 10), ('oo', 11)]
```

Comment: but I need it in descending order, basically descending order just for the first condition (x[1]) and normal order for the second one(x[0])

Comment: oooops sorry I missed the point while testing it :\